# Populating Map of Lists

Tags: apex

I'm trying to populate a map of lists.  I'm using a temporary list variable for each iteration and then to use map.put() to populate the map of lists with the temporary list variable.  But when I clear the temporary list to repopulate it, it also clears the list in my map.  Can someone explain what's happening and suggest a different approach?  Here's the relevant code snippet.

Map/List Declaration:

```
public list <timesheet__c> Timesheets {get;set;}
public map<ID,list<Budgeted_Timesheet_Distributions__c>> mapBTSDistributions {get;set;}
```

My code where I populate the map:

```
for (Timesheet__c TS : Timesheets){
                for (Budgeted_Timesheet_Distributions__c BTSD: BTSDistributions){
                    If (BTSD.Timesheet__c == TS.id){
                        tempBTSDList.add(BTSD);
                    }   
                }
                mapBTSDistributions.put(TS.Id, tempBTSDlist);
                System.debug ('Map for' + TS.Employee__c + 'is' + mapBTSDistributions.get(TS.Id));//map will have a value
                tempBTSDlist.clear();
                System.debug ('Map for' + TS.Employee__c + 'is' + mapBTSDistributions.get(TS.Id)); // map will be blank
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using two SObjects here that have a relationship to one another, I'm not sure if you even need a separate `Map<Id, List<Thing__c>>`.

You can use a parent-child subquery (a.k.a. a Left Outer Join) to make SOQL automatically group all your child records into a collection that is reachable using the Id of the parent record.

```
Map<Id, Timesheet__c> timesheetsWithBudgetedDistributionsMap = new Map<Id, Timesheet__c>(
    [ SELECT Id, <other fields>, 
          (SELECT Id, <other fields you need> FROM Budgeted_Timesheet_Distributions__r) 
      FROM Timesheet__c 
      WHERE <filters>]
);
```

`Budgeted_Timesheet_Distributions__r` is my best guess at the relationship name. You can see/verify what the relationship name actually is by looking at the field definition of the relationship field to `Timesheet__c` on `Budgeted_Timesheet_Distributions__c`

Getting at the child records would look like this:

```
List<Budgeted_Timesheet_Distributions__c> distributions = timesheetsWithBudgetedDistributionsMap.get(ts.Id).Budgeted_Timesheet_Distributions__r;
```

There are situations where there are enough child records that you won't be able to directly access the child records (seems to be tied to the need for Salesforce to call queryMore()). In that case, you'll end up needing to use code very similar to the code you provided in your question.

```
for (Timesheet__c TS : Timesheets){
    for (Budgeted_Timesheet_Distributions__c BTSD: TS.Budgeted_Timesheet_Distributions__r){
        if(!mapBTSDistributions.containsKey(TS.Id){
            // By initializing the key/value pair of the map on the first
            //   occurrence of the key, we won't need to worry about whether or not
            //   the key exists in the map after this if block.
            // That allows us to factor out (of this if block) the (generic) code for adding new items
            //   into the list stored for any given key.
            // Keeping code outside of nested blocks is generally a good thing, 
            //   and this also means we don't need an else block.

            mapBTSDistributions.put(TS.Id, new List<Budgeted_Timesheet_Distributions__c>());
        }

        mapBTSDistributions.get(TS.Id).add(BTSD);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a temporary variable, your lists are all going to share the same reference, even after you put them in the map. You would need to put a cloned list into the map instead.

It would be better to just not share a reference at all. You don't even really need the outer loop to do this grouping operation, nor even any cached `List` variable. That's unnecessary verbosity.

A common algorithm to group child records by parent:

```
byParent = new Map<Id, List<Child__c>>();
for (Child__c child : allChildren) // BTSDistributions
{
    if (!byParent.containsKey(child.Parent__c)) // BTSD.Timesheet__c
    {
        byParent.put(child.Parent__c, new List<Child__c>());
    }
    byParent.get(child.Parent__c).add(child);
}
```

Comment: Another, slightly different, approach to this is to break the reference to the temporary list by cloning it (the temporary list) when putting it into another collection (and before clearing the temp list). I don't know if there are any situations where I would use this approach over the one given in the answer though.

Comment: Yeah I describe that process using words, but didn't include a code sample because it seems less efficient and quite verbose.

Comment: oh, derp, don't mind me.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for helping me learn.  I definitely needed the code sample!

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you do need a separate `list` variable and cannot use one of the other solutions presented, you can use `new List<Budget_Timesheet_Distributions__c>()` instead of `clear()`.  This will assign a new `list` instance to the variable - since the variable is just a reference, the `list` you put in the `map` will not be affected.

```
for (Timesheet__c TS : Timesheets){
    for (Budgeted_Timesheet_Distributions__c BTSD: BTSDistributions){
        If (BTSD.Timesheet__c == TS.id){
                tempBTSDList.add(BTSD);
            }   
        }
        mapBTSDistributions.put(TS.Id, tempBTSDlist);
        tempBTSDlist = new List<Budget_Timesheet_Distributions__c>();
    }
}
```